# CouchDB caching clean on views

Tags: caching, cron, couchdb, influxdb

I use CouchDB in order to be able to import data into InfluxDB from the same time changes are made to the CouchDB view.

The problem with CouchDB is that it persistently caches data, i.e. if I have a count that only counts data from today, it will only add those numbers to those from yesterday and so on. I created a cron that cleans those view/s with POST **/mydatabase/_view_cleanup** but nothing happened

view example

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.timestamp && doc.unsafe) {
    var today = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    var thatDay = new Date(doc.timestamp * 1000).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    if (today === thatDay) {
      emit("unsafe-count", 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Reduce: **_count**

I want to clear cache every day at 00:00:01 to get real count data

Comment: [_view_cleanup](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/compact.html#db-view-cleanup) is for optimizing away stale (unused and lingering) index files.  I have to ask, why `doc.timestamp * 1000`?

Comment: Also, the most important question is: What is your view query?